# How to deal with buffers in glfw

Tags: python, opengl, buffer, glfw

I'm trying to use a `glfw` context with `pyopengl` to create a simple framework to render 2D environments. My problem is that as soon as I introduce moving objects, the screen gets cluttered with 'shadows' of where an object was in the frame before.

I suspect I have to clear *some* buffer to reset the screen but the only glimpse I get of *any* buffer is the `glfw.swap_buffers()`call.

To be short I'm lost as to where even begin and as a self-taught 'modern' opengl user I can't even tell which gl-fuctions are deprecated.

My draw call:

```
def triggerRedraw(self):
    shaders.glUseProgram(self.completeShader)
    try:
        self.vbo.bind()
        try:
            glUniformMatrix4fv(self.cameraMatrixPointer, 1, True, self.cameraMatrix)

            glEnableVertexAttribArray(self.vertexPositionPointer)
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(self.vertexColorPointer)

            stride = 5*4
            glVertexAttribPointer(self.vertexPositionPointer, 2, GL_FLOAT, False, stride, self.vbo)
            glVertexAttribPointer(self.vertexColorPointer, 3, GL_FLOAT, False, stride, self.vbo+8)

            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6)

        finally:
            self.vbo.unbind()
            glDisableVertexAttribArray(self.vertexPositionPointer)
            glDisableVertexAttribArray(self.vertexColorPointer)
    finally:
        shaders.glUseProgram(0)


    # Swap front and back buffers
    glfw.swap_buffers(self.window)

    # Poll for and process events
    glfw.poll_events()
```

I'm switching out the entire VBO in the main loop then call `triggerRedraw` to make objects move. What I observe is that it first fills the front buffer, then the back buffer, so that I see 2 overlapping objects on frame 3 instead of only 1 object, 3 objects in frame 5 and so on.

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Are you clearing before you start drawing? (For each frame)
 ``glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT)``

Comment: That definitely worked. I wasn't sure if `glClear` was deprecated or not, nor did it cross my mind that the `GL_BUFFER_BIT`s are global and therefore always accessable. Thanks a ton.

Comment: GL4 reference: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/. You'll probably get by just fine with GL3.3+ features. If you nail Textures, FBOs, Shaders and VAOs you are well off!

Comment: Also do yourself a favour and make sure that you open a 3.3 (or higher) opengl context with glfw that is core and forward compatible. (NO BACKWARDS COMPATIBLITY for deprecated stuff)

Comment: Do I do that by setting `glfw.window_hint` version major and minor to 3.3 and specifying `#version 330` in my shaders? cause then he tells me my `glDrawArrays` call is invalid. Unless that's deprecated?

Comment: `glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE)`

Comment: .. and `#version 330` in shaders as you say